# What types of automotive fluid are prone to hygroscopic deterioration?

Tags: fluid

I would like to compile a list of [hygroscopic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hygroscopic) fluids where sufficient water absorption leads to performance deterioration. A sensitivity ranking would be great as well.

The obvious one is brake fluid, where over time the chemical makeup of the fluid leads to spongy brake feel.

Are there other fluids which should be refreshed periodically for this reason?

Comment: You could start here : http://www.hygroscopiccycle.com/hygroscopic-compounds/

Comment: Ethanol is one to be aware of.

Comment: I guess "air" is a good candidate but refreshes itself often enough.

Comment: Engine oil is not hygroscopic in the sense that it actively attracts moisture, but it can be contaminated with water over time especially if a car is not allowed to warm up properly. According to your current definition it has no place on your list but it still can degrade because of moisture contamination.

Comment: There just aren't that many different types of fluids in a car.  You already know about brake fluid, and that's the main one.

Comment: @MadMarky that's right, I wouldn't put anything on this list if it doesn't lose efficacy due to "unforced" moisture absorption. It wouldn't surprise me if most fluids are going to suffer from performance degradation should they be forcibly mixed with water.

Comment: Petrol, Brake Fluid, Clutch Fluid, that's pretty much it.